# What's the difference between [sql-like] and [like-operator]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I am not a bona fide SQLizard, so this may be a naive question, but what's the difference between [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) and [like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator)? Should they be one-and-the-same?

[sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) excerpt:

> The `LIKE` operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column.

[like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator) excerpt:

> The like operator in SQL allows you to compare strings using wildcards. While not as powerful as a regular expression, often it's good enough.

If yes, probably merge into [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like), a la [sql-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update), [sql-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert), [sql-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-delete) ([sql-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) is a synonym of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql))

[image: venn diagram]

If no (as slugster suggests), perhaps clarify the tag excerpt/wiki (I'm not familiar with `like` as an operator, so I disqualify myself). Maybe rename it to [vb-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like) (or is it used in other languages?)

Comment: Where did the image come from?

Comment: Ok, I see it now... it is the distribution of questions with the specific tags.  you may want to explain the image to eliminate confusion

Comment: It's not a distribution *per se*, but a Venn diagram.

Comment: I couldn't think of the name off the top of my head... but yes.  Still, the lack of a description makes it seems like it is blindingly obvious what the diagram represents, and it isn't

Comment: There isn't any difference. Both tags look to be used arbitrarily to represent the same thing.

Comment: I've just upvoted the synonym request here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/like-operator/synonyms

Comment: VB has a [Like operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) for string operations which need not have anything to do with SQL (or facebook)

Comment: @Plutonix the like operator tag wiki description indicates that the tag is specifically for SQL `The like operator in SQL allows you to compare strings using wildcards. While not as powerful as a regular expression, often it's good enough.`. Maybe that should be changed then. In practice I only can find [a few questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator+vb.net) using the tag for that though.

Comment: @Plutonix: sounds like a `vb-like-operator` tag is called for then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my experience is that most people inclined to ask a LIKE related question are not that fussy about tags.  just as likely to be tagged `Microsoft`, `VisualStudio`, `visual`, `basic` and `.NET` (many tagged as DO NOT USE)

Comment: Was approved by the community vote.

Answer (score 2):

The [like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator) is used to discern the comparison type 'like', the [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) is the SQL specific version of that.

A [clean up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142241/i-would-like-to-clean-up-like) was started some time ago on the [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) tag, as it was meaningless by itself - especially with the amount of facebook oriented questions that were coming in.

I'm pretty sure there's another question dealing with this somewhere, I'll see if I can dig it out.

Comment: `especially with the amount of facebook oriented questions that were coming in` -- ***facepalm***

Comment: The clean-up post is apparently deleted (10k+?)

Comment: Thanks @NickT, it's been deleted as it was off topic for Meta.SE, I'll see if I can get it moved back to this Meta.

Comment: I may have duped it then (to downvotes) here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286388/194586