# Cleaning up tags like [like]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, clean-up

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286471/i-would-like-to-clean-up-like?lq=1) aims to remove [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like), but I'd also like to clean up the fleet of tags surrounding things like it:

- SQL's `LIKE` keyword/operator (for which there is a tag: [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like))
- Visual Basic's `Like` operator (for which [like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator) is supposed to be used, but is usually applied to SQL questions, because it's also an operator)
- Social media (Facebook) likes (for which there are a couple, more specific tags: [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like), [google-plus-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-one), but it's the "generic" tag)

Proposed Changes

1. Rename [like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator) (which is vague and many people use for SQL questions) to [vb-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like), [vb-like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like-operator), or similar.
2. Rename (possibly after a mass cleanup to retag the SQL/VB questions as appropriate) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) to [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like). Non-Facebook, social media "like" questions are few in number and they can be tagged with the overarching API (if it exists).
3. Blacklist [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like). Besides, nobody likes anything on this site. Only upvotes.

Comment: Didn't you already [ask this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272873/whats-the-difference-between-sql-like-and-like-operator)?  This seems very related, if not a duplicate of your previous one.

Comment: @bluefeet that was for sql-like/like-operator, which I sort of understood after an answer. I could copy-paste everything there, but I figured this is more of a follow-up in light of gaining clarity from that.

Comment: I'm confused if the downvotes are because this is perceived to be a duplicate (OK, I can move stuff there, but I don't see any close-as-dupe votes) or bad (in which case have you seen the [like] page?)

Comment: "excel function time like now" priceless.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicated. The objective of this discussion is getting rid of the [like] tag, the other is about differentiating when two tags should be used.

Comment: Note: this has [already been discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142241/146015) (currently 10K+ only) prior to the Meta split, but it's been left on Meta.SE and closed as off topic. I'm seeking to get it reopened and migrated.

Comment: Whether or not this is a duplicate, the fact remains that the mentioned tags are still confusing and nothing has been done about it. The suggestions by the OP are sound and should be implemented.

Comment: like like I like think like that like i like agree like yeah.

Comment: @Lundin Yes it should be implemented (the previous discussion has now been migrated here), but have you seen the scale of the issue? It isn't growing as fast now because there are fewer facebook questions, but it's gonna require a whole village for the clean up.

Comment: @slugster I generalized this a bit.