# We [like] to clean up bad tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

After checking a search page I noticed a lot of questions that are tagged [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) and [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like).

Now I know what a 'like' is on Facebook, but as someone who doesn't center their life around Facebook it also means other things to me, like 'similar'.

At the current count there are 1179 questions tagged with [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like). Of those, 520 are also tagged [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook). This leaves 659 questions that are not Facebook related. There are already 2090 questions tagged with [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like).

Can we synonimize [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) to [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) for questions that are also tagged [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)? This will help show facebookers that a [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) is a vastly different thing to a [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)[like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like).

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+like) for those willing to help in the clean up (<s>there are currently **649** still to be done</s>).

(Note that this is a follow-up question to this one from just on a year ago: [The “like” tag is used for various meanings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104023/the-like-tag-is-used-for-various-meanings).)

Comment: No synonym, retag and get rid of the tag.

Comment: [Visual Basic Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) anyone? No takers? :(

Comment: Are there tools so we can split it? I Would then suggest remove like where question also tagged with facebook-like, then change tag from like to facebook-like where tags facebook or facebook-graph-api and then rename all likes to sql-like  where tagged together with sql, mysql, sql-server, database, oracle and tsql. After this it is hopefully only 100 to 200 for the rest of the questions. And we can manually finish it.

Comment: I see that some questions are about custom (non facebook) likes or youtube likes, is there a social-media-like tag and if not, is it needed?

Comment: There's also a vb-like and perhaps a few more that would be needed.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +44/0. A1 (Saying Yes): +41/0. A2 (Saying Yes): +10/0. A3 (Neither): +2/0. A4 (Retagging Obs): +3/-1 A5 (Saying Yes) +5/0

Comment: Wait, is this request now in phase 2 after only SEVEN YEARS in phase 1? Wow, we're really catching up aren't we.

Comment: [tag:like] is is a dependent tag. Tagging a question with only l[tag:like] does not add information to the post. It is only meaningful when it has another tag like [tag:sql].

Comment: @MrLister, Yes! There have been many similar requests that have not been handled since ages (there is enough to last till 2030). As you are a high rep user, feel free to join in the mini tag burns, where there are <50 questions in that particular tag, and help make a dent in the burn backlog. :-)

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +107/-2.  A1 (Saying Yes): +90/0. A2 (Saying Yes): +20/0. A3 (Neither): +2/0. A4 (Retagging Obs): +3/-4 A5 (Saying Yes) +8/-4. A6 (Saying Yes): +15/0. A7 (Saying Yes): +5/0. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: What about the fun of removing the fun? Are some posts more equal than others?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) for questions related to Facebook's like functionality.
- Use [social-media-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-media-like) for questions related to the like button on various social media sites.
- Use [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) for questions related to the SQL LIKE operator.
- Use [nspredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nspredicate) for questions related to the NSPredicate Like operator.
- Use [vb-like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like-operator) for questions related to the Visual Basic Like operator.

## Progress:

The [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=like),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blike%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blike%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blike%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blike%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190791)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=286471)

[image: burnination progress chart]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### [Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307009)

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: That makes [tag:vb-like-operator] and [tag:sql-like] both about _operator_, but with distinct naming conventions. Well, we can eventually make [tag:sql-like] a synonym of [tag:sql-like-operator] in the future if that is a naming issue.

Comment: @Cœur, yeah, the rename can be done easily.

Comment: Small question: Questions about creating a like/dislike button with some code should be tagged with...? I tag them with [tag:button], but should they be tagged with [tag:social-media-like]?

Comment: @double-beep if they are related to social media buttons, tagging them with both is better. Otherwise, just [button] is enough.

Answer (score 99):

I say we cut out the middleman and just burninate [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like). The word is used in too many contexts that are completely different.

Comment: In general I would agree with you 100% but that leaves me wondering: what do we do with the `like` that is used in conjunction with sql/database queries?

Comment: There is a [`mysql-like`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-like) tag... Perhaps a `sql-like` tag should exist.  Look's like someone already thought of that - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141455/organize-tags-for-sql-key-words

Comment: Might get to this over the weekend.

Comment: That would be an option, but these questions really need some attention. Trawling through them, approx 30-50% of them need closing or deleting.

Answer (score 23):

I agree with Nicol Bolas: Remove [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) as that tag is used with different meanings.

If there is the need, a more specific tag should be used, for example [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like). To notice that this is what has been done with [drupal-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-views), which is referring to the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module for Drupal. Using [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal), and [views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/views) has a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 17):

In order to disambiguate this tag usage, following the tag excerpt description is a good start (i.e., preferring [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like)).

But before burning, we may want to address what to do regarding non-[facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and non-[sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) questions. Quoting a comment from Aldwoni (emphasis is mine):

> some questions are about custom (non facebook) likes or youtube likes, **is there a social-media-like tag and if not, is it needed?** – Aldwoni

Some Questions that would illustrate this non-facebook social user/page/post/comment like or +1 feature:

- [PHP like button(counter) inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698208)
- [About like system (such as facebook like system) using myisam Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563977)
- [Inserting multiple id's in a mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997959)
- [Running if statement based on the results of multiple selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282416)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813341
- [MySQL - Get most "liked" users in the past month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885579)
- [Send Like/Dislike to database with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653679)
- [Should I insert and delete record OR insert and update record for LIKE/UNLIKE button? Which one is more cost effective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536672)
- [disabling more than one "like" per post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978229)
- [Retrieving "likes" tied to users from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010766)
- [Retrieving like counts on entries from SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016959)

Shall we have a replacement-tag for it?
[Nick T answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286518/1033581) was proposing the addition of [social-media-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-media-like).

I propose [likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/likes), which is a plural form, so it will still be easy to find and won't interfere with programming languages keywords.

---

There is also the [Visual Basic Like Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator), noticed by Erik von Asmuth.

- [for loop to return exact match but need to update to return similar match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934208/)
- [Postcode Validation and like notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342097/)
- [Is there a javascript equivalent to VB's "LIKE #"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415786/)

[Nick T answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286518/1033581) was proposing the addition of [vb-like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like-operator).

Or maybe [vb-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like)?

---

There is also the [NSPredicate Like Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868):

- [Search substring with wildcard symbol using NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637735/)
- [NSPredicate and BEGINSWITH with CloudKit : Field value type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792249/)

There may not be a need for a tag for this one. [nspredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nspredicate) is enough.

---

There is also a Powershell like:

- [Powershell Like Wildcard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760032/powershell-like-wildcard-issue)

---

There are also questions asking for a `like` statement that doesn't exist:

- [VB Script if statement: Sub not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979470/vb-script-if-statment)
- [JPA - Criteria Query - Search for Integer using "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230680/jpa-criteria-query-search-for-integer-using-like)
- [How to make "LIKE" query work in MONGODB using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798098/how-to-make-like-query-work-in-mongodb-using-php)
- [Aggregating data.table with sum, length and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976471/aggregating-data-table-with-sum-length-and-grep)

There may not be a need for a tag for this one. (Or [like-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-function)?)

Answer (score 7):

Content migrated from [Should we, [like], burninate this tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363750/5958455) (my own duplicate).

---

#### Tests for burnination criteria:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Yes, and No. It may describe the content, but it's ambiguous (see 4).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Uh, yes. Both [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) are on-topic here.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   I don't think so. The tag wiki excerpt **explicitly** says:

   > DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Use [facebook-like] for the Facebook Like functionality. Use [sql-like] for the SQL reserved keyword LIKE.

   Is the ALL CAPS text in the excerpt loud enough?
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Absolutely no. It is used both as [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587577), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839810), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701162)) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) ([4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718669), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616951), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295621)). Refer to 3 (it's explicitly requested not to be used).

   See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104023

Can we get rid of this tag? It currently has 1690 questions tagged. Among the 30 latest questions (as of now), 6 refer to Facebook Like (or whatever a "like" button), 22 refer to SQL `LIKE` clause, and the other 2 refer to something else.

We already have [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) for the majority of those questions, so this tag is unlikely necessary, and is better <s>kicked off</s> burninated.

Answer (score 6):

Proposed changes from my other question:

1. Rename [like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator) (which many people misuse for SQL questions) to [vb-like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-like-operator)*
2. Rename [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) to [social-media-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-media-like)*
3. Blacklist [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like). Besides, nobody likes anything on this site. Only upvotes.

Clean-up should be done at some point, but nothing is getting merged, so it doesn't matter in what order it is done.

<sup>*I'm not married to these names, but they can be re-renamed later if they're not perfect. At least they're clear for now. Better suggestions?</sup>

Comment: [tag:facebook-like] seems to be pretty well established. And [tag:like-operator] has [around 50% SQL questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator+sql), which should be retagged as [tag:sql-like].

Comment: @KevinBrown yeah, *some* `like` questions should be `facebook-like`, but not all as some are more generic. Also, are you saying `like-operator` should be merged with `sql-like` (I kinda disagree...the VBA like is a valid topic I guess...) or just that current `like-operator` is a total mess (strongly agree).

Comment: I was saying that [tag:like-operator] is a mess and the SQL questions should really be tagged [tag:sql-like], which was created because of this question (two years ago). The same applies to [questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like+sql) both [tag:sql] and [tag:like] as well.

Comment: And [after excluding the common, non-social tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like+-facebook+-sql+-sql-server+-facebook-like+-mysql+-tsql+-facebook-graph-api) I can't find that many [tag:like] + social questions that would suggest the need for [tag:social-media-like].

Comment: @KevinBrown the first question on `like` is a YouTube one, but on second thought, a generic `social-media-like` tag is almost as worthless as `like` to begin with (probably isn't a standardized "like" API or whatever).

Answer (score 5):

They will keep coming back because the wasteland that is Facebook.stackoverflow.com requires a non-Facebook tag on a question and there are a non-stop flow of (off topic / dupe / low quality) questions about the Facebook like button (that don't get an answer as evidenced by the generous 50% reply rate Facebook Dev team posts on their weekly metrics blog post).

Comment: Are you sure there has to be a non-Facebook tag on every question? [These](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55417863/4284627) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55110503/4284627) only have Facebook tags, and those are just examples. And if the [like] tag keeps coming back, it can blacklisted.

Comment: @DonaldDuck This answer is over six years old. At the time, there was a [Facebook-specific subdomain](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/24/facebook-stackoverflow/) which presumably had that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) + one of ([sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver), [t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/t-sql) and other obviously SQL related tags) should be retagged to [like-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-operator) (not [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) as that's just a synonym).

Comment: `sql-like` is actually distinct from `like-operator` (which is the thing in VB/VBA)

Comment: @NickT That's not how it's used now, nor is that how the tag wiki reads (or ever read).