# Should we burninate [chemistry]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request, meta-tags

*The Phase #2 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag), is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system.*

---

As-is, the [chemistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) tag is off-topic for Stack Overflow. There are 117 questions tagged and 250 followers. (Of which the followers should probably be on [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) instead).

Many of the questions relate to solving problems in chemistry using computers, but the motivation for the question is irrelevant to the actual question. Is this just a meta-tag which can be burninated?

At the very least, there should be usage guidance in the tag info to prevent misuse.

> Chemistry is a natural science concerned with the constitution and properties of elements and chemical compounds (molecules), their transformation through interactions in their outer electron shell (chemical reactions) and the interaction of chemical compounds with electromagnetic radiation.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40675127/5743988) an example of a relatively recent off-topic question.

**It fails at criteria 2 from "When to burninate", namely the concept isn't even on topic for the site.**

---

Some usage guidance has now [been added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342959/its-not-you-we-just-have-bad-chemistry/342970#comment442805_342970):

> For programming questions that involve chemistry - such as questions about programmatically working with chemical formulae, simulating chemical processes, or using chemistry-related libraries and APIs. Non-programming questions about chemistry are off-topic here, but may be on-topic on chemistry.stackexchange.com.

Is this enough? Are there questions which reasonably fit this description? I feel this may still be too broad, and that the chemistry-related APIs should have their own tags.

---

I have finished doing an initial sweep of closing off-topic questions. The next stage of my effort will be to go back and remove the tag from questions which aren't "really" about chemistry. I have not removed the tag from actual chemistry-related questions (pending community approval).

Comment: So, you want to dissolve [chemistry] because its meaning is too dilute?

Comment: Let's decide on the basis of **clearly on topic** questions. Is [Parsing a chemistry equation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129245/parsing-a-chemical-equation) an equally valid question *without* the tag `chemistry`?

Comment: @RadLexus I think the solutions to that question have no specific relationship to chemistry. The tag is just there because the word "chemistry" appeared in the post.

Comment: I also spoke with [a regular](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5210517/m-a-r) on Chem.SE, and [they agreed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35483782#35483782) it can be burninated.

Comment: Why would someone on Chem.SE be familiar with the types of tags that are useful on Stack Overflow? As a regular on Stack Overflow, should I be consulted when Chem.SE makes decisions about their tags?

Comment: @CodyGray Chem.SE [sometimes gets questions about programming](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35483740#35483740) for chemistry purposes, so there's a bit of overlap with the communities there.

Comment: @CodyGray If they were previously using the [chemistry] tag in migrated questions, I wanted some from Chem.SE to explain if that tag was important or not.

Comment: @Makyen For the heck of it, I did a search for [homeopathy](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=homeopathy). I got 18 hits.

Comment: @Undo Is this burninate request still under review? Some time has passed and I'm not sure if a decision has been made.

Comment: @4castle Mind flagging it again? I can't really deal with it right now, but someone else should be able to.

Comment: Stats at the start of [feature]ing: Q: 28/7, [A1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342960): 21/10, [A2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342970): 23/7, [A3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342981): 9/3.

Comment: @usr2564301 (c-n-p previous comment) I would say "yes", it's like "how to parse html using an html parser". "How to parse X?" can do it without the X tag, since the structure of what's being parsed is fluid. "How to parse a sentence?" "How to parse a math equation?" "How to parse a mathematical identity?" etc. we would need many, many tags. BTW, that question is trying to use something akin to a tokenizer, not a parser designed to parse chem formulae. The answer is using regex, mind you.

Comment: @Jean-François Please don't edit the title when the post is [featured].

Comment: Stats at the end of [feature]ing: Q: 68/18, [A1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342960): 38/31 - community disagreed, [A2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342970): 85/19 - comm agreed, [A3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342981): 17/5 - comm agreed, [A4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345011): 30/-4 - comm agreed [A5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345021): 6/-12 - comm disagreed. (remaining 2 had < 5 votes). A tough one here, but concentrating on the two poles - A2 said not to burn and got +62/-12. A4 said to burn and got +30/-4. As A2 is more than twice A4, the request is declined

Comment: FWIW, this strikes me as somewhat akin to [the flappy-bird tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really), insofar as it is used to describe the problem in some way.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok, got it.

Answer (score 90):

I'm not sure that this tag is worthless. *In particular*, I think that [Yvette's rationale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342960/1709587) for burninating - namely, that

> Chemistry has nothing to do with programming.

- is a bad reason to burninate.

Yvette is certainly right that chemistry is not innately programming-related, but from looking at the tag it seems clear that people doing chemistry-related software development come across a bunch of chemistry-specific programming problems. The questions [Parsing a chemical formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974362/parsing-a-chemical-formula), [Smallest Set of Smallest Rings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071425/smallest-set-of-smallest-rings), and [Plotting an IR Spectrum with Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772026/plotting-an-ir-spectrum-with-gnuplot) are good examples. It's also certainly the case that chemistry is something that Stack Overflow users can have expertise in - either because it's the industry they work in, or because they did a degree in it in a past life, or just because they've learned a lot about chemistry for some other reason. Aren't these points, together, sufficient to justify keeping the tag?

Note also that we have several other tags for industries and problem domains that are not innately programming-related, including [finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finance), [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics), [accounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounting), [statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics), and [linguistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) (all with >100 followers). The rationale that Yvette applies here would also suggest that all these tags should be deleted. But I'd argue against that for the same reason: those domains contain unique programming-related problems, and there are people who are domain experts who will benefit from those tags helping them seek those problems out.

Comment: Well, [finance], [accounting] and [linguistics] should be burninated for sure, too.

Comment: So... what has to do what you use the code for to a software developer?

Comment: @Braiam that sentence is a little confusing. A typo?

Comment: @Braiam I'm not arguing that simply because code is being used in a particular industry, questions about it should have that industry's tag. A question like "How do I make the title pink on my chemistry website?" is not a chemistry-related question and shouldn't be tagged as one. But other questions - while still being programming questions - are *innately* related to particular industry, the one about parsing chemical formulae being a good example. It's *that* class of question that I think benefits from having industry- and domain-specific tags - ones where the domain certainly does matter.

Comment: @YvetteColomb lack of punctuation: what has to do "what you use the code for?" to a software developer?

Comment: I think we need a better tag wiki then

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I agree. [Done.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

Comment: @MarkAmery well, why not having [economics] tag too, or [administration], or [operational-research], or [econometrics], or [physics]? All those use programming one way or another.

Comment: @RadLexus I would say "yes", it's like "how to parse html using an html parser". "How to parse X?" can do it without the X tag, since the structure of what's being parsed is fluid. "How to parse a sentence?" "How to parse a math equation?" "How to parse a mathematical identity?" etc. we would need many, many tags. BTW, that question is trying to use something akin to a tokenizer, not a parser designed to parse chem formulae. The answer is using regex, mind you.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm going to move this comment to a more appropriate place: underneath the original post, rather than under one of the answers. Just a mo'.

Comment: @Braiam: "bueller? bueller? .. braiam? braiam" ;') As it is a comment on my comment, please move it as well?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for someone to be an expert on [chemistry] within the domain of Stack Overflow. The questions span all kinds of programming languages, and the answers don't (or shouldn't) require background knowledge of chemistry in order to answer.

Comment: *"Chemistry has nothing to do with programming.
- is a bad reason to burninate."* It's [criteria number 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/347499) in determining if something should be burninated. I think it's pretty relevant.

Comment: @usr1234567 are you aware there's entire field called computational linguistics?  They give phds in it.  There's a huge overlap of linguistics and programming.  Questions in that field go from everything to how to handle RTL languages to natural language processing.  I wouldn't be burninating that tag.

Comment: @GabeSechan Probably http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for such question. SO is about programming questions.

Comment: @usr1234567 ANd if the question is about how to implement a trigram model?  Or how to correctly identify phonemes in Java?  Then its a programming question.  I'm not saying a comparisson of Hebrew and Italian would be on topic here, but a question like either of the above would be appropriate and appropriately tagged linguistics.

Comment: @GabeSechan Still, it wouldn't help to get answered when the tag [chemistry] was added.

Comment: A missing point here, IMO, is that I cannot imagine an on-topic question on SO that would only be tagged [chemistry]. And [from help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): *If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag*. Not a strict rule, but to keep in mind though.

Comment: @GabeSechan Every computer program is ultimately an effort to solve a real-world problem, unless it's (a) an exercise or dummy program meant to help someone learn or demonstrate a programming concept or (b) tooling or infrastructure to facilitate the writing of more programs. But the real-world problem domain doesn't actually provide anything more than circumstantial context for questions that are on-topic here. The fact that a particular problem arises in the context of computational linguistics may be worth mentioning in the question body, but that doesn't mean it's useful as a *tag*.

Comment: @KyleStrand THe field of computational linguistics assumes a certain set of known techniques and programming concepts.  If that isn't worthy of a tag, nothing is

Comment: @GabeSechan "Nothing" is? Piffle. Technologies (e.g. programming languages and environments) are clearly *more* relevant than problem domains that happen to have "known techniques" associated with them. By "known techniques," I assume you mean algorithmic approaches to common problems in the domain. But in most cases, I would expect questions that actually require this sort of algorithmic knowledge to be likely candidates for the "too broad" flag. Also, as noted in other comments, there is already http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/, where such questions would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @KyleStrand All your doing is proving your utter ignorance of that field.  You still think its about asking questions on linguistics.  Its not-  its programming questions that require special techniques and knowledge. It is absolutely worthy of a tag.  If it isn't worth of a tag, neither are things like client-server.

Comment: Parsing a chemical formula is not programatically different from any other form of parsing. Lets say a mathematical equation, some reverse polish notation, a script language etc etc. The smallest set of smallest rings is a sheer algorithm problem that is more suitable for http://cs.stackexchange.com/. Etc etc. Very few programmers make programs for programming's own sake. There's always an application with a purpose.

Comment: "*Parsing a chemical formula is not programatically different from any other form of parsing*" - this seems like obvious nonsense to me, at least given any useful definition of "programatically different". The question of how to parse a chemical formula is clearly not a duplicate of a question about how to parse a URI, and the people who arrive at those questions from Google are going to do so because they want to parse the exact thing that the question is asking about.

Comment: The approach is the same. You specify tokens and delimiters. You build up some sort of expression tree. You process it. You present the results.

Comment: @Lundin Sure (or you use tools that do those things for you, like regexes or parsing libraries). But at the level of abstraction that you're having to zoom out to here, it's not just all *parsing* problems that are the same, but all *programming* problems. "The approach is the same. You determine the logic your process has to follow, and then specify it using the syntax of your programming language." Just as true as your observation, but both points are clearly impractical; there are frequently useful things to be said about how to solve *specific* problems.

Comment: But it sounds as if there is not one specific problem, but rather several, unrelated problems: understanding the task, ask at http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/, designing an optimal algorithm for the task, ask at http://cs.stackexchange.com/, then implement it in some programming language, possibly on-topic on SO if specific enough.

Comment: @GabeSechan If you say so. Here's a concrete example of a question that seems like it might fall under the umbrella of "computational linguistics questions that require domain knowledge", but which, indeed, was flagged and removed: http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/497/2041 If the OP had the start of a corpus generation tool but was struggling with a specific programming road block, the question probably would have been on topic, but I'm not sure domain specific knowledge would have been necessary.

Comment: @MarkAmery Okay, if you break problems down that way, I'm not sure questions about the "determine the logic" step are *ever* on topic here. In general we require questions about specific programming problems to already have some programming done.

Comment: @KyleStrand - *"In general we require questions about specific programming problems to already have some programming done"* - assuming that by this you mean exhibiting the code of a failed or incomplete attempt at a solution in the question, then I strongly disagree. That's an old fight here. Look at the highest-upvoted questions on the site; most don't meet that standard (and would be much worse questions if they did). Some are one-liners!

Comment: What Kyle says is quoting the help center: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Or if you want it more digested, lets try Tim Post's ["Would it take a programmer to understand answers to this?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343114/792066)

Comment: @Braiam huh? Kyle hasn't "quoted" that at all, nor does the point of his that I'm contesting in any way follow from the section you have quoted from the help center. Problems do not require an exhibit of a failed solution in order to be practical, answerable, or unique to software development.

Comment: "specific programming problems" == "problem that is unique to software development" If you don't see it...

Comment: "Problems do not require an exhibit of a failed solution in order to be practical, answerable, or unique to software development", yet you argue that we need chemistry tag...

Comment: '*"specific programming problems" == "problem that is unique to software development" If you don't see it...*' - I have no idea what this is meant to mean. Please at least speak in sentences to give people a chance of understanding you.

Comment: If you don't see a direct response to your previous comment...

Comment: *"If you don't see a direct response to your previous comment..."* - for goodness' sake, *please* write in sentences rather than cryptic fragments. I *do not have the slightest clue* what you are trying to express.

Comment: "*you argue that we need chemistry tag*" - No, that's not quite what I've argued here. If there were no chemistry tag, I wouldn't much care whether one was created. I *am* arguing, though, that the tag *has value* that shouldn't be wantonly destroyed. We don't *need* pretty much any individual piece of content on Stack Overflow, but that doesn't mean that it's okay to arbitrarily destroy stuff. Applying a high standard of scrutiny to decisions to delete other people's work *is* a principle that I care strongly about.

Comment: @MarkAmery I don't believe English is Braiam's first language, so to my taste your "please at least speak in sentences" and "cryptic fragments" comment come off a bit rude/dismissive. Successful communication requires some effort from *both* parties, and it honestly seems like you're intentionally trying *not* to understand what Braiam is trying to say.

Comment: @KyleStrand while I believe you're right about Braiam not having English as a first language, I think that the weird fragments here are simply a stylistic choice. Braiam is perfectly capable of writing long, complex sentences in perfect (or at least good-enough-to-understand) English when he wishes to. And no, I'm not intentionally trying not to understand; if *you* understand, feel free to elaborate.

Answer (score 39):

The problem with this tag is that it doesn't really tie the questions together in a meaningful way. In other words it fails [Burnination Test #4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). Let's consider some actual questions

- [Parsing a chemical formula from a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116786/parsing-a-chemical-formula-from-a-string-in-c) - Parsing a string using C#
- [Typing chemical formula using markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537232/typing-chemical-formula-using-markdown) - Displaying a chemical formula in HTML
- [Chemical balancer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562614/chemical-balancerjava) - Data types in Java

They're all *about* chemistry problems, but each describes a *different type of coding problem*. So even if I had a coding question about chemistry, this tag is all but useless to me because they're just the subject of the problem. This is why I disagree with Mark Amery, on this

> Note also that we have several other tags for industries and problem domains that are not innately programming-related, including finance, physics, accounting, statistics, and linguistics (all with >100 followers).

This is a terrible reason to keep a tag. It's like saying we need a tag for cars, because people can write code to run a car. Or run inside a car's computer. Or use while riding in a car. Tags should describe what language or coding concepts are being used or asked about. Tags that merely describe the subject of the problem should have no place here. Put those words in the title or question, not the tag.

Comment: I disagree, the context can describe the concepts used very concisely. For example code for cars would be real time code that needs to be reliable and failsafe.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Why can't those details be added to the question body? Why would there be a generic tag. As stated by many here what "chemistry" can mean is subjective.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I fail to see how a tag can promote "real time code that needs to be reliable and failsafe". I mean, the software I write at work has those same constraints (and no, I don't work on cars). By contrast, I can easily see how a generic tag like this can promote lots of noise. "My car won't drive straight." "How do I make a car follow GPS?"

Comment: Additional note: domain expertise in chemistry is relevant; the parser couldnt be done in regex by someone unfamiliar with chemistry formula rules

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble The rules are simple enough that someone without domain expertise could easily determine what the OP's code is doing incorrectly, though; and if that were not the case, the OP should be able to _explain_ what the parser is doing incorrectly and what the desired behavior is-- at which point the parsing is indeed strictly a _programming_ problem that happens to have a useful application in chemistry.

Comment: "Parsing a chemical formula form a string in C#" is way, way more specific and answerable than "Parsing a string using C#".

Comment: @MilesRout We're not proposing banning the use of the word "chemistry" from questions and question titles.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: *For example code for cars would be real time code that needs to be reliable and failsafe.* => not when it's the entertainment system, or the climate-control system, or... just because it runs in a car doesn't imply anything by itself.

Comment: If you were going to permit [chemistry] for this reason it suggests that I should tag most of my posts with [finance] (my current job) as there could be some underlying requirement for it to be FCA compliant, even if it's something like "How do I sum a column of numbers?" and @MilesRout I disagree with your comment on parsing, as parsing *everything* is going to be unique to whatever you're parsing unless it has been asked before. Would 'How do I parse an ISBN number in the format LNNN' be tagged as [literature] or [book-filing]?

Comment: Maybe there's a solid objection to my view here, but I personally don't think you've managed to articulate it. I think the key point where I don't understand your argument is where you say *"They're all about chemistry problems, but each describes a different type of coding problem."* Couldn't I just as accurately say about questions in, for instance, the PHP tag *"They're all about PHP problems, but each describes a different type of coding problem."*? In what *concrete way* does the PHP tag "tie together" questions better than the chemistry tag? Don't both fields have experts?

Comment: I think [Chemistry] is to Chemistry questions what [Programming] would be to programming ones. You're encompassing the entire field of chemistry in your tag.  But PHP is known only by specific PHP users. A PHP guru could answer most PHP questions. But a PhD Chemistry professor wouldn't be able to answer most chemistry questions, only those in their field plus simple general questions. I would say if you could write no more than a big textbook that covers 99% of the topic, then it's a good tag. If you have to write 50 textbooks as you would with Chemistry, then it's so broad as to be unhelpful.

Comment: @MarkAmery Apples to oranges. Chemistry is a field of science. PHP is a programming language. So the PHP tag ties together coding problems solved with PHP (which are inherently on-topic). Chemistry is neither a programming language, nor is it a way to solve coding problems. The tag is being used to indicate the problem being solved is chemistry. That's a bad reason to have a tag.

Comment: @NibblyPig No because the format for ISBN is pretty clear. The subtleties of chemical formulae have the potential to be subtle. For example, `COOH` means `H-O-C=O`, not `C-O-O-H`. So a domain expert could be very useful for that question. Parsing an ISBN? Not so much.

Comment: @MilesRout wait, how can the asker not tell that in the question?

Comment: @Braiam There's no reason to assume that the asker of this hypothetical question would know all the subtleties of chemical formulae.

Comment: @MilesRout woah, there. So how else would a bunch of techies tell him how to do it, if he himself isn't sure? At very least, you need the asker to describe the initial and final state you want the data you are processing, otherwise, who else would know?

Comment: @Braiam Well *if it's tagged chemistry* then someone that knows chemistry and is on StackOverflow is likely to know. Jesus christ, this isn't a difficult concept.

Comment: @MilesRout Which is where your logic falls trough. I'm a economics, and I'm sure as hell that I wouldn't allow such tag to be created so people can ask pure economics questions on the site... not that it matters anyways because the software we use is the same that all programmers use, not one bit different (R, for example).

Comment: *"so people can ask pure economics questions on the site"* - no! The existence of an economics tag does not imply that a question asking for an explanation of Arrow's Impossibility Theorem is on-topic, any more than the existence of the Android tag implies that it's okay to ask what the best dating app for Android is. Questions *on Stack Overflow* that are tagged as chemistry should *involve both chemistry and programming*, such that they're of interest to (and answerable by) people working *in the intersection of those two fields*. As @MilesRout says, this isn't a difficult concept.

Comment: Tags aren't categories though. If I ask how to calculate VAT at 20% in a kendo UI gridview column I wouldn't tag it as [Maths] and [Finance]. If you have a nuanced question go to the chemistry stackexchange to figure out how to do it, and post on SO for how to implement it. The only overlap might be chemistry programming languages, but in my opinion even that shouldn't be tagged as [Chemistry] anymore than C# should be tagged as [Object-Oriented-Programming] as I don't see the relevance of the programming language. If there's a chemistry language like Chem# then tagging it [Chem#] is enough.

Comment: @MarkAmery and all the off topic questions that the OP found were because "lol", right? You know perfectly well that people do not interpret tags that way, so we better don't leave it to a chance.

Comment: @Braiam I have at least four different objections to your latest comment, not least of which is the unnecessary antagonism and accusation of bad faith, but as Machavity has already pointed out, a decision has been reached on this BR (for better or worse) and further discussion is mostly pointless. I'm going to cease replying further here and get on with my day doing something less joyless than squabbling on the internet. I suggest you do the same, and wish you a good day either way.

Comment: [car] might not exist (and is too broad/non-technical) - try [automotive] and [vin]. maybe one of [obd2] [obdii] [obd] should exist too.

Comment: [car] doesn't exist because [we renamed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369276/rename-car-to-r-car)

Answer (score 13):

I believe a distinction should be made, at least for the purposes of this discussion, between:

- Questions that only involve chemistry as circumstantial background which is not relevant for the answers. The examples in [Mark Amery's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342970/2751851) (e.g. [*Plotting an IR Spectrum with Gnuplot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772026/plotting-an-ir-spectrum-with-gnuplot)) are of this kind. I don't think such questions need the [chemistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) tag.
- Questions that are about software, libraries and APIs that deal specifically with chemical problems (computational quantum chemistry, molecular dynamics simulations, etc.). For instance, one such question which is on-topic is [*Computational chemist using MDAnalysis - How to instantiate Atoms?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31582128/2751851) [1]. In the case of these questions, the tag is arguably useful, specially considering that programmers with experience with computational chemistry software are more likely to have ran into the relevant software at some point, or at least to be able to understand the terms of art in the relevant documentation.

[A very similar discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314756/2751851) was once held about the [bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics) tag. There is also a [cheminformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheminformatics) tag, though note that the "cheminformatics" term [has a narrower meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheminformatics).

---

Footnotes:

[1]: For the sake of contrast, an *off-topic* example is *https://stackoverflow.com/q/36057046/2751851*, which clearly [should have been asked at chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3426/3683).

Comment: I agree there's a distinction, but the on-topic question you posted for the second group wouldn't suffer from removing the [chemistry] tag. It already has a much more specific and on-topic tag for their specific software that would be much more likely to attract people who can answer the question. The other two tags you mention are much more oriented towards this site.

Comment: Can those tags be used alone in a on topic question?

Comment: @4castle In principle, yes; however, the fact that that tag has six followers, five questions and three answers between them doesn't exactly raise hopes from the point of view of the asker. (Not that using [chemistry] helped the asker in this case either, of course...)

Comment: @Braiam [mdanalysis]: yes. [bioinformatics] and [cheminformatics]: unlikely, but not entirely implausible (I wonder if there are any existing examples). [chemistry]: well... not really. Something like [molecular-dynamics] *might* pass your test, though.

Comment: (@Braiam This is not really relevant, but I'm now wondering about what would be the optimal formulation of your test. For instance, a question about a library for a specific language always (?) has at least two applicable tags.)

Comment: Does this tag makes it really more likely that it will get an answer? The answer is normally no. In fact, the libraries tags were created since there are people that know way too much about how a library works rather than the language in general.

Comment: @duplode I think the mdanalysis tag on that example question is more useful than the chemistry tag. Something tagged with mdanalysis is obviously going to be about chemistry, because that's what the mdanalysis program is for; it entirely precludes/obviates the need for a separate chemistry tag.

Comment: @TylerH That is a reasonable argument, and [mdanalysis] is certainly an useful tag as far as long-term classification of questions go. However, this kind of library tag might be too niche to attract any significant number of followers, which means a broader tag might be useful for leading potential answerers to the questions. (Admittedly, this tag doesn't necessarily have to be [chemistry]. Perhaps it would be a good idea to rename it [computational-chemistry], or to have a [molecular-dynamics] tag that covers the specific technique MDAnalysis implements.)

Comment: Some researchers are [using DNA to store data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_digital_data_storage), so chemistry may be more pertinent than ever soon.

Comment: @TinyGiant [indeed](https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/5xt0gl/science_ama_series_im_yaniv_erlich_my_team_used/).

Comment: If only some fraction of posts with the [chemistry] tag actually fit this strict definition, is there any point in having the tag? Or is that a bit too meta-meta. Chemistry is a bit of a broad topic in that example post. Sorta like tagging a question about correct rivet tension in an x993-b steel beam as [architecture]. Not sure how it'd be so useful...

Answer (score 6):

Chemistry has nothing to do with programming. I say we burninate it.

[It has 117 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) combined with other tags that are not all related. We don't need tags about business logic domains.

Comment: _"Chemistry has nothing to do with programming."_ It's a grey field, there are a lot of chemistry mechanisms, that can be solved algorithmic. Think DNA.

Comment: That's a problem domain, not related to the programming. There's plenty of equations used in many scientific domains, even in beauty and health. We don't need business domain tags

Comment: But, but we have a lot of business domain related tags. That's a big task to push all of them away. Let's start with [tag:hft], that's one of the fields I hate most of all.

Comment: [Computational chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_chemistry) has a lot to do with programming :-) However, questions about the chemistry aspect might fit better in the respective tags at [Chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry) or [SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh jeeze, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41284651/1858225) was the top result in that query when I looked.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is an example of a tag being used to add context to a question instead of including the context within the post itself. Unless a decent following of people are coming onto Stack Overflow and specifically searching for questions tagged [chemistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) then I don't see a requirement for it.

Comment: There are 267 followers of a tag with only ~100 questions. When there are twice as many followers as there are questions, that suggests a hyperactive interest that should probably not be handwaved away.

Comment: Fair enough (I didn't actually go and check the amount of followers) so there is in fact a decent following and you're spot on.

Comment: @TylerH we need to know who they are and why are they following the tag. If they answer anything but "I answer questions with this tag", I would remove it.

Comment: @Braiam Better get started on interviewing them then

Comment: @TylerH that made me chuckle!

Answer (score 3):

Stackoverflow questions should be very specific as per the FAQ:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Therefore if you are asking any chemistry related question, you should already know what you are trying to achieve.

If you ask "I have an atom with an angular velocity of 24 and I want to use the formula a=b+v-u/t and put the value into a textbox, here is my attempt but I am getting the wrong answer" then it's an acceptable question. The chemistry element is completely irrelevant and adds nothing to the question. A chemistry expert is no more or less likely to be able to answer this as it is a *programming* question.

If you ask "I have an atom, how do I calculate its angular velocity and put it into a textbox?" Then you're asking two questions, one of them is off-topic. You've failed to meet the criteria above as this isn't a specific programming problem.

In this instance you should post on chemistry stackexchange asking how you calculate angular velocity. Once you understand what it is you want to do, then you can ask the programming question on here.

Tagging the second question as [Chemistry] serves no purpose other than inviting chemists to solve the chemistry part of your problem. This isn't what stackoverflow is about, as it is about programming not chemistry.

The other instance you may think to use [Chemistry] is if you are using a science based programming language like CP2k. However there is still no relevance to tagging this as Chemistry, as you should again be asking a specific programming problem and not asking how to perform chemistry itself. Therefore tagging it as [CP2K] should be sufficient for Chemists to help you.

At this point you may argue that Chemistry students know a wide range of languages therefore they would have to subscribe to [CP2K] amongst 30 other programming languages based on science. So if we had a generic [Chemistry] tag then that would help group them.

However to that I say I subscribe to [C#], [Asp.net] [Asp.net-mvc] [sql] [php] [jquery] [javascript] [html] and a bunch more. We don't have a [Microsoft-Stack] tag or [Front-End-Stack] etc. as a category to make things easier, so we shouldn't have [Chemistry] for this reason either.

Comment: From what I've gathered, the reason this burnination request was declined is because there are instances of programming problems which a chemist would be very familiar with, and tagging the question as [chemistry] is able to bring those people to those questions. Take, for example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742985/5743988). Would the answerer have found that question if it wasn't in the [chemistry] tag? Possibly, but they would have needed to search specifically for that question.

Comment: Essentially, the assertion that *"A chemistry expert is no more or less likely to be able to answer this as it is a programming question."* is incorrect, because there may be common pitfalls in implementing the formula which they can't foresee, or they may be reinventing the wheel and should instead be using a library that does it for them. Both of those answers need domain knowledge.

Comment: 3 issues I see 1) If there are pitfalls in the person's chemistry methodology then it belongs on chemistrySX. If there are pitfalls in the actual programming implementation it should be independent of chemistry knowledge or you dilute the purpose of SO. 2) Chemistry is so broad that it's unlikely to significantly attract chemistry people that are able to identify those specific pitfalls unless they happen to be an expert in the exact field being implemented. 3) You can argue the same for most questions "How do I add 20% vat to my total in javascript?" if they were tagged [finance] or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Subject-matter tags such as chemistry serve a useful purpose, which is to identify the programming problem with the subject. Yes, of course, chemistry is not inherently about programming in any way; neither are dozens of other subjects. If one is interested in a subject, and in programming, one can search here for questions which fall in the intersection. That is a valid, constructive use of SO; the presence of subject-matter tags is a tiny cost which gives us that substantial benefit. None of this is specific to chemistry. It applies equally well to other subject-matter tags.

Comment: I will add [economics] to all my questions from now on, even the ones where I'm just trying to show a image in html. This will be so fun.

Comment: "which gives us that substantial benefit" [citation needed]

Comment: @Braiam he is citing the immediately previous sentence (hence "'that' benefit"). The benefit is searchability by tags.

Comment: @TylerH well, I have yet to see which programmer in their right mind will search for "chemistry", I don't do so for "economics" and I'm a bit of both. BTW, tags sole costumer are answerers, therefore the ones that should benefit of any tag are them. If a question doesn't make more likely to the answerer find the question (see my first sentence), what purpose would serve?

Comment: @Braiam Your BTW sentence is completely false. People looking for existing answers or for duplicates of a question they are about to ask also use tags. What makes you think tags are only for people who write answers?! Stack Overflow's purpose is not so that you can have questions to answer, it's so that programmers can come here and find or get the answer to their questions.

Comment: @TylerH so, are you saying that the help center is a farce? "Tags are a means of **connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories."

Comment: @Braiam No, I'm saying that your cherry picking is quite harmful to the discussion. Let me quote some from that page, too: "**A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question**", and "**Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you**."

Comment: @Braiam Importantly, that page is about *Asking a Question*, so verbiage on the subject of tags will be *in the context of asking and answering*.  Tags are also mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching and http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics as well as the Tour page: "**Tags make it easy to find interesting questions. All questions are tagged with their subject areas.** [...] **Click any tag to see a list of questions with that tag, or go to the tag list to browse for topics that interest you.**" Perhaps you should read more of the Help Center than just one section...

Comment: @TylerH and how that invalidates my argument? I'm quoting the "What are tags, and how should I use them?" which I believe it describes in the most simple terms the purpose of them. Also, your quotes doesn't support your argument more than it does mine, ie "help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you", why would you find questions interesting or relevant if it's for the ultimate purpose of answering them?

Comment: @TylerH in other words, while you can use tags for the task you describe, that's not the main purpose: helping people find the questions they are able to answer.

Comment: @Braiam Sorry, the main purpose of tags is searchability without any focus on who is doing the searching. But if there were a focus on it, it would be focused on the largest demographic of users (viewers, or 2nd largest: askers), not the smallest (answerers).

Comment: @Braiam It invalidates your argument because you are taking one sentence out of a specific context and not only interpreting it closed-mindedly (it's not a zero-sum game like you suggest), but also applying it to *all* contexts, which is ridiculous. As for why someone would want to find questions, many people like to learn things, or read interesting material. Have you never looked at the views of a question before? They usually outnumber the answers by several factors. If what you say were true, there would be nearly as many answers as views on a question, every time.

Comment: @Braiam, your comments here all seem to support the value of [chemistry] as a tag.

Comment: @fixer1234 [citation-needed]. BTW, the first comment was sarcasm.

Answer (score -5):

I'm having problems plotting aggregated macroeconomics data in R with zoo objects and plot, should I add a [macroeconomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macroeconomics) tag? No. It has nothing to do with the problem at hand: coercing R to do what I want.

The structure of the data or what it represents is irrelevant for the problem at hand. The same with [chemistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry), the fact that what I'm manipulating is related to the science, doesn't make my problem any different.

Comment: As I commented previously, this misses the distinction between a question that is *inherently about* a problem domain (e.g. "how do I parse a chemical formula?") and a question where the asker *incidentally happens to be working in* a problem domain (e.g. "how do I make my chemistry website pink?"). That I can't think of any programming problems that inherently involve economics suggests that we shouldn't have an economics tag, but I've [already listed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342970) several programming problems that inherently involve chemistry and are only of relevance to chemists.

Comment: @MarkAmery and as said previously: we are programmers! What you use the code for is irrelevant.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Is a question about how to parse a URL into its components "irrelevant" to the topic of URLs? If not, how is a question about how to parse a chemical formula "irrelevant" to the topic of chemistry? Or are you saying that the purpose of the code is "irrelevant" to something else that I'm not seeing, rather than "irrelevant" to the tag? I really don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: Particularly in the academic world, you'll find I think that it *does* help to have a domain in questions like plotting.  In many academic disciplines there are certain common ways of doing things that might not be particularly relevant to programmers at large but which a programmer in that domain might know - and some of that knowledge might be assumed in the question, so a regular [tag:r] user might not understand the nuance of the question while a chemist who also knows [tag:r] might.

Comment: @MarkAmery As I explained on a comment on Machavity's answer, even the chemical-formula example doesn't seem compelling to me. There was a particular parsing error that could be easily expressed without requiring knowledge about chemistry; once the issue has been expressed in such a way that it's amenable to a programmatic solution, the higher-level problem domain is irrelevant.

Comment: @Joe yet, I have been able to get by without it. In fact, I prefer someone outside of my field to tell me what I'm doing wrong, since they have several times more expertise in their field (aka programming) than anyone on my field. Obviously, I wouldn't expect a programmer to tell me what I'm doing wrong in economics, because that isn't their field.

Comment: @Joe I agree, but I'm not sure a *tag* is necessary to show that domain. Just mention it in the post. What are the numbers for domain-specific (or domain-relevant) questions in [tag:chemistry] that could not be found by just searching with the chemistry keyword, vs the numbers for bad questions in the chemistry tag/questions that abuse the chemistry tag?