# Are questions about the internals of the Linux kernel on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

I recently encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082081/questions-for-linux-kernel-booting-up) in the [linux-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) tag that contains several questions related to booting within the Linux kernel. The questions are, for the most part, pretty specific and well formulated in my opinion.

My first thought was to vote it as off-topic for being a question about general software and suggest moving it to the Linux/Unix Stack Exchange site. However, looking at the description of the [linux-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) tag, the question seems to fit the tag perfectly:

> This tag is for questions about the internals of the Linux kernel itself - particularly about writing code that runs within the context of the kernel (like kernel modules or drivers). Questions about writing userspace code in Linux should generally be tagged [linux] instead. Since the internals of the Linux kernel are constantly changing, it is helpful to include the precise kernel version(s) that you are interested in.

The linked post is *definitely* a "question about the internals of the Linux kernel itself," although the OP doesn't ask about specific code.

I have a few questions, then:

1. Should I have voted to close this as a question about general hardware/software or was I in error?
2. Should I have flagged this for the moderators to migrate to Linux/Unix SE?
3. Is the *entire tag* off topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: OP could have added a bit more context around that question, but I think it's a good fit for the site (even though it looks like a bit of a marathon, upon reading, it's pretty obvious what he's trying to grasp).

Comment: In *this particular case*, the question is actually four questions in one, some of which are not even obviously related to each other. That makes it problematic and argues for its closure. But *in general*, I very much agree with Tim Post: questions about the internals of the Linux kernel are on-topic here, just like questions about the internals of any operating system, microarchitecture, or API.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A great way to think of it is ...

#### *Would it take a programmer to understand answers to this?*

And in this case, that answer is most decidedly **yes**. I've been active in that tag since I joined the site in 2009 and you see *plenty* of questions that merely surround observed behavior of the kernel that folks don't quite understand. These are good questions to have, as they tend to bring out in-depth answers and most importantly, really help someone wrap their head around how the kernel works.

Most *meaningful* stabs at kernel development first entail a pretty long period of studying, observing and truly understanding existing behavior.

Comment: Excellent definition of StackOverflow's "domain" in general! This should be go into some onboarding tutorial for new users.

Comment: @Sliq brings up an interesting point - is it worth making a FAQ post on the topic (maybe generalizing it to questions about the internals of *any* operating system)?

Comment: It would appear the question was closed..