# Are questions asking for input on our own things off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

While running trough the triage queue, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094378/how-can-i-design-active-directory-product-to-startup-my-biz) gem. Read it through once. Sounded reasonable. Read it through twice and marked it "Unsalvageable" under "Blatantly off topic".

What I'm wondering is - are these kinds of questions actually off topic, seeing as they have no real programming related content? And if so, what the best flag would be to raise on any that come up in the future?

Comment: You need to read what is being asked: what features should my product have/my company implement. If you don't know what your product is supposed to do, don't ask us instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, they're actually off-topic.

In the context of this question, look *closely* at what is being asked.

> I have developed one open source lib few years ago to management Active Directory easily which has been used in Lenovo, Sony, Tempursealy, Boostsolutions... landpyactivedirectory.codeplex.com
>
> For now I want to startup my biz base on this lib, and I have rewrite the lib and build one official site http://fewbox.com, could you please kindly to help me what features I need to deliver first? Thx a lot!

Of emphasis is the second paragraph - they want to start up their business based on this library, and they want clarity on what features they need to deliver first.  **What features you need to deliver first** is not something that a layman with no insight into what their business actually ***does*** can reasonably and concisely answer.

Honestly, we're not consultants, and we don't have a crystal ball to see into their individual company's needs.  We can't help them with a problem as abstract as this.

For a juxtaposition on this, [read this answer by Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343114/1079354).  If it wouldn't take a programmer to understand the answers to a question like this, *perhaps* it's not on-topic.

<sup>I say "perhaps" because I've had a heuristic for sniffing out off-topic questions, and Tim's only came up *today* and really spoke to me.</sup>