# Rename [car] to [r-car]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[car](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/car)

It's increasingly obvious having a [car] tag is inviting people to ask questions about cars, and not R, despite having an excerpt that says it's not about cars.

Renaming the tag should help solve the problem.

Comment: (1) There are also a few questions about [`car` in a Lisp/Scheme/Racket context](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html), but those most likely don't need this tag either. (2) The influx of automobile-related questions seems to be about [0--5 questions per month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/car+-r+-lisp+-scheme+-racket+-common-lisp)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Gotta raise the bar. At least suggest we rename it to [KARR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KARR_(Knight_Rider))

Comment: Given the current excitement of self-driving vehicles and the high probability that such excitement will not end "any time soon," this renaming makes sense to me. A further (maybe more important) question would be: "what to do with the car tag?" Should it be black-listed as too broad? Strict standards adopted and enforced across multiple languages may be possible, but difficult.

Comment: @Imo The prospect of people using Stack Overflow to write self-driving car software is both awesome and terrifying at the same time

Comment: @Machavity `'my car crashed, what did I do wrong'` closed as duplicate of `/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/`

Comment: I thought that a car inherited from class vehicle and has_many wheels.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: closed as cannot reproduce. I had my robot car drive straight at 12 people. It didn't crash once and only one person died, but that was due to a heart attack. Please supply more details in the question.

Comment: @Machavity Wouldn't surprise me if some of it *did* come from Stack Overflow.