# Send [automotive] to the scrap yard

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

We have [automotive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automotive) with just 22 questions, 20 this year (odd - was there a cleanup last year?), which seems very vague compared to the actually useful but even quieter [android-automotive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-automotive), [automotive-grade-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automotive-grade-linux) and [iot-for-automotive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iot-for-automotive).

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

No, it's a meta-tag.

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Connected cars are on-topic here, but just "car" isn't.

3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

No. Specific technologies like [can-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can-bus) are meaningful, though.

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. Some of the contexts are really Linux/Android/etc, but *in a car*, other are about specific vehicle-related sensors, etc.

---

Since there's only 22 questions, re-tagging is easy, but it would be nice to get the tag blacklisted also.

Comment: Pretty much the same as the [bioinformatics burn request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314756/17034).  Making software work in rain and snow for 150 thousand miles is not simple.

Comment: Given just 22 question, as well as not being simple it's not interesting... Also, none of the questions seem to be about actual automotive issues. One can be a bioinformatics expert, I think, but not automotive, so it's not really the same thing, IMO.

Comment: Clearly you have no idea whatsoever what kind of software runs in a car.  A BMW E60 has 15 processors standard and 40 in options.  Very obscure bus protocols and topologies to get them to talk to each other, you have to have walked the walk to talk sensibly about it.  So sure, it isn't interesting to you.  Why it has to be uninteresting for the programmers that work on this is not obvious.  Add the tag to your profile's Ignored Tags section and you'll never have to look at them again.

Comment: Sorry, I am currently developing software for vehicles, so I am well aware, but here it is only gathering dust.

Comment: Well, we [already fixed the car](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369276/rename-car-to-r-car) so I say go for it

Comment: Most of these questions has little to do with automobiles, but with combustion engines (specifically with hardware that could be embedded into one). There is a single one that I can say is grossly off topic (not a bad question, just not a question for SO), where the question asks [how to replace a hardware controller for their bike, since original broke down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54057508/792066).

Comment: The thing is easy to do, just retag those that are about android HIDL, those that are about the embedded devices or their interphases, and then look at the rest.

Comment: My god I love these puns

Answer (score 6):

I don't agree with these burnination. As [pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385000/send-automotive-to-the-scrap-yard#comment696446_385000), this is no different than the bioinformatics tags, which was recently declined. There are numerous issues unique to automobile development.

Also, I don't understand why "connected car" is on topic but "car" is an off-topic Meta tag that must be burninated.

I also don't understand why the fact that it only has 22 questions is relevant. There are plenty of low-traffic tags on Stack Overflow; are we going to burninate all of them, too?