# Should we, [like], burninate this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Do we [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like) it?

#### Tests for burnination criteria:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Yes, and No. It may describe the content, but it's ambiguous (see 4).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Uh, yes. Both [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) are on-topic here.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   I don't think so. The tag wiki excerpt **explicitly** says:

   > DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Use [facebook-like] for the Facebook Like functionality. Use [sql-like] for the SQL reserved keyword LIKE.

   Is the ALL CAPS text in the excerpt loud enough?
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Absolutely no. It is used both as [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587577), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839810), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701162)) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) ([4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718669), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616951), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295621)). Refer to 3 (it's explicitly requested not to be used).

   See also: [The "like" tag is used for various meanings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104023)

Can we get rid of this tag? It currently has 1690 questions tagged. Among the 30 latest questions (as of now), 6 refer to Facebook Like (or whatever a "like" button), 22 refer to SQL `LIKE` clause, and the other 2 refer to something else.

We already have [facebook-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) and [sql-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-like) for the majority of those questions, so this tag is unlikely necessary, and is better <s>kicked off</s> burninated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286471/i-would-like-to-clean-up-like